# Error while executing Node registerAdmin.js Blockchain Tuna Fish App

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, smartcontracts

I am trying to execute the tuna fish blockchain app, see below git example

https://github.com/hyperledger/education/tree/master/LFS171x/fabric-material/tuna-app

while running " node registerAdmin.js " I am getting following error

```
tuna-app/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:746
    async _createOrUpdateChannel(request, have_envelope) {
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npm and node version was quite old. I upgraded the version and error solved

use below command to upgrade NPM & node -

```
npm install -g npm@latest

npm install -g node

npm rebuild
```